# Why does this regex fail at passing onto php/mysql?

Tags: javascript, c#, php, regex

```
public static bool CheckFields(AS_AccountInfo regInfo, string passwordConfirm, 
string emailConfirm, ref string errorMessage)
{

    errorMessage = "";

    // Validate the data in the fields (make sure it matches their type
    if ( !regInfo.fields.CheckMySQLFields (ref errorMessage) )
        return false;

    if (regInfo.GetFieldValue("password") == null || 
        (AS_Preferences.askUserForEmail && regInfo.GetFieldValue("email") == null))
    {
        errorMessage = "Account info not set up correctly..! Missing fields..!";
        return false;
    }

    // Password must match
    if (regInfo.GetFieldValue ("password") != passwordConfirm) {
        errorMessage = "Passwords must match..!";
        return false;
    }
    // If an email has been entered
    else if (AS_Preferences.askUserForEmail && regInfo.GetFieldValue ("email") != "") {
        // It must be valid
        if (!new Regex (@"^[\w!#$%&*+\-/=?\^_`{|}~]+(\.[\w!#$%&*+\-/=?\^_`{|}~]+)*@"
            + "@leeds.ac.uk").Match (regInfo.GetFieldValue ("email")).Success) {
            errorMessage = "Invalid email..!";
            return false;
        } 

        // And match its confirm
        if (regInfo.GetFieldValue ("email") != emailConfirm) { 
            errorMessage = "Emails must match..!";
            return false;
        } 
    }

    // All good..!
    return true;
}

 <? php
   $link = try_mysql_connect($databaseHostname, $databaseUsername, 
$databasePassword, $databaseDbName, $databasePort);

$from = $emailAccount;

$info = $_POST['newAccountInfo'];
$requireEmailActivation = strtolower($_POST['requireEmailActivation']);

$fields = explode($fieldsSeparator, $info);


$fieldNames = "";
$fieldValues = "";
$email = "";
foreach ($fields as $field) {

$words = explode($fieldNameValueSeparator, $field);

$fieldName  = $words[0];
$fieldValue = $words[1];

$fieldName = stripslashes($fieldName);
$fieldValue = stripslashes($fieldValue);
$fieldName  = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$fieldName);
$fieldValue = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$fieldValue);

if ($fieldName == "")
continue;

}

if ($requireEmailActivation == "true") {
    if ($fieldName == "username")
    $username = $fieldValue;
    if ($fieldName == "email"){
    $email = $fieldValue;
}

// Store it
$fieldNames  .= "`$fieldName`,";
if ($fieldValue == "")
$fieldValues .= "NULL,";
else
    $fieldValues .= "'$fieldValue',";

 }
$fieldNames = rtrim( $fieldNames, ",");
$fieldValues = rtrim( $fieldValues, ",");

$query = "INSERT INTO accounts 
(" . $fieldNames .")
VALUES ( " . $fieldValues . " )";

try_mysql_query($link, $query);
?>
```

It results in:

> MySQL error 1054 (Unknown column '' in 'field list')
>   When executing
>
> ``` INSERT INTO accounts 
>   (``)
>   VALUES ( NULL ) ```

Can someone explain this? I've attempted to de-limit various characters in the expression but still no success. In my view the reg expression should work, and it's just the leeds.ac.uk element which it's tripping over but I can't work out why?

Comment: Where do you use / store the regex?

Comment: NB I am aware this does not protect against injection!!!

Comment: Yet it's not obvious where you use this regex either as a literal string or a functional parameter.

Comment: Apologies I have included more information now @revo

Answer (score 0):

I think some brackets are in the wrong place. Indented and beautified part of your PHP code:

```
foreach($fields as $field) {
    $words = explode($fieldNameValueSeparator, $field);
    $fieldName = $words[0];
    $fieldValue = $words[1];
    $fieldName = stripslashes($fieldName);
    $fieldValue = stripslashes($fieldValue);
    $fieldName = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $fieldName);
    $fieldValue = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $fieldValue);
    if ($fieldName == "") continue;
}

if ($requireEmailActivation == "true") {
    if ($fieldName == "username") $username = $fieldValue;
    if ($fieldName == "email") {
        $email = $fieldValue;
    }

    // Store it

    $fieldNames.= "`$fieldName`,";
    if ($fieldValue == "") $fieldValues.= "NULL,";
    else $fieldValues.= "'$fieldValue',";
}
```

Look at

```
if ($fieldName == "email"){
```

and

```
    if ($fieldName == "") continue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's the regex failing and not the PHP? Have you tried echoing out the variables before the query?

Also I don't know it in pure javascript but in Jquery you could replace the regex with something like:

```
$var= something@leeds.ac.uk;

if ($var.split("@")[1]!=="leeds.ac.uk")
{
//alert invalid email
}
```

Comment: I'm now sure it's the PHP failing. Still throwing up php/mysql error 1064. Something to do with how the data from the input fields are having trouble passing to my database

Comment: try commenting out the query then echoing the $fieldNames and $fieldValues or try print_r($fieldNames) if they're arrays and check if they contain what they should contain.

Answer (score 0):

To be sure of fixing your code easy take the error info as a start point of solution.
It Specific your in :

```
$query = "INSERT INTO accounts (" . $fieldNames .")
```

1- then echo the value of $query to see what became in it.

2- done forget to remark the remains of code to concentrate on the current point

3- I see the wrong inside this line:

```
$fieldNames  .= "`$fieldName`,";
```

check the (`) usage here by echo ($fieldNames) value